# Error when several Actions with the same Shortcut

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a `TabView`. Each `Tab` is in the separate file (here for simplicity I composed all the code in one file). I'd like to launch some function using <kbd>Enter</kbd> key or a `Button`. All is ok when I click the `Button`s. But when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, nothing happens (`onTriggered` event handler is never executed) and I also get an error:

> QQuickAction::event: Ambiguous shortcut overload: Return

If I have only one `Tab` the problem does not occur and the `onTriggered` handler is correctly executed.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Item {
    width: 640
    height: 480

    TabView {
        id: tabView
        currentIndex: 0

        anchors.fill: parent
        Layout.minimumWidth: 360
        Layout.minimumHeight: 360
        Layout.preferredWidth: 480
        Layout.preferredHeight: 640



        Tab {
            id: tab1 
            active: true
            title: "One"

            Item {

                id: item

                x: 16
                y: 8

                width: 640
                height: 480

                Action {
                    id: calcDataAction
                    text: "Run"
                    shortcut: StandardKey.InsertParagraphSeparator
                    tooltip: "one"
                    onTriggered: {
                        console.log("one")
                    }
                }

                Button {
                    action: calcDataAction
                    id: calcButton
                    x: 20
                    y: 20
                    height: 40
                    width: 100
                }
            }
        }


        Tab {
            id: tab2 
            active: true
            title: "Two"

            Item {

                id: item2

                x: 16
                y: 8

                width: 640
                height: 480

                Action {
                    id: calcDataAction2
                    text: "Run"
                    shortcut: StandardKey.InsertParagraphSeparator
                    tooltip: "two"
                    onTriggered: {
                        console.log("two")
                    }
                }

                Button {
                    action: calcDataAction2
                    id: calcButton2
                    x: 20
                    y: 20
                    height: 40
                    width: 100
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve it?

As a workaround I could use the following `shortcut` binding in the `Action` :

`shortcut: tab1.activeFocus ? StandardKey.InsertParagraphSeparator : ""`

But the problem is that, first I need (don't know why) to click on all tabs' headers, before events could trigger...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Action` has a property [`enabled`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-action.html#enabled-prop), like almost all visual and non-visual types in QML. If enabled - by default it is - an `Action` can be triggered.

Having all the `Action`s active at the same time does not make sense since only a single `Tab` can be visible. Hence, an approach to solve the issue would be to just enable *one* `Action` at a time, the one associated to the currently visible `tab`, that is:

```
enabled: <tab_id>.visible
```

Following your code, a minimal example looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 300
    height: 200
    visible: true

    TabView {
        id: tabView
        anchors.fill: parent

        Tab {
            id: tab1
            title: "One"

            Action {
                id: calcDataAction
                enabled: tab1.visible
                shortcut: "Ctrl+O"
                onTriggered: console.log(tab1.title)
            }
        }

        Tab {
            id: tab2
            title: "Two"

            Action {
                id: calcDataAction2
                enabled: tab2.visible
                shortcut: "Ctrl+O"
                onTriggered: console.log(tab2.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```